# Any reliable benchmark for frame interpolation?

Tags: framerate, frame-interpolation

I want to use frame interpolation to convert videos from 30 FPS to 60 FPS. I found many programs for that: [Davinci Resolve](https://redd.it/pxw655), [Flowframes](https://nmkd.itch.io/flowframes), [SmoothVideo Project](https://www.svp-team.com/), [Topaz Video Enhance AI](https://www.topazlabs.com/video-enhance-ai) (Chronos model), etc.

Is there any reliable benchmark for frame interpolation that would show me how these programs compare against each others (in terms of output quality + computational cost)?